# What is the simplest instruction set that has a C++/C compiler to write an emulator for?

Tags: c, cpu, computer-architecture, c++, architecture

I'm looking into writing a little software emulator that emulates/runs instructions.

The easiest would be to invent my own instruction set, but I thought it would be more fun if I write an emulator for an instruction set that already has a C++/C compiler.

What is the easiest instruction set/architecture that has a (hopefully stable) C++ and/or C compiler?

By easiest, I mean the least number of instructions.

Comment: emulator for what? Because what describe sounds like you want to build a CPU.

Comment: Do you mean "what is the simplest instruction set that **could have** a C compiler?", or  "what is the simplest instruction set that **already exists and does have** a C compiler?"  The answers are different (the answer to the first is "anything that's Turing complete").

Comment: @Marcus Müller I want to emulate a existing cpu with instruction set that has a c++/c compiler. No I don't want to build a cpu. Yes, I do think it might be fun to TRY to implement it on an fpga, but I don't think I know enough about fpga's for that.

Comment: this may give you some ideas ... https://esolangs.org/wiki/Main_Page ... https://esolangs.org/wiki/Language_list

Comment: @jsotola that's about programming languages, not about CPUs!

Comment: @TimWescott I mean an instruction set that already exists and DOES have a c/c++ compiler. So preferable a existing cpu with c++/c compiler, where preferably the cpu has a simple instruction set so it's easier for me to implement.

Comment: @appmaker1358 so you want to write a software cross-platform CPU emulator. Good news: the first thing you do when designing CPUs is practically always write an emulator, so basically for *every* ISA you can get an emulator as reference implementation.

Comment: @appmaker1358 if you design an FPGA to "emulate the execution of an instruction set", what you've built is a processor with that instruction set, hence my confusion about the term "emulator".

Comment: @Marcus Müller Yeah, I might once try to design a cpu with isa myself and port gcc or something, but I first need to learn way more. Hence I want to write an emulator for an existing architecture so there is plenty of existing code and other info to help me.

Comment: yeah, as answered in my answer: there's plenty to pick from, and modern choices, too, that come with multiple existing emulators you can use to test and verify your own emulator.

Comment: @Marcus Müller you are correct that if I write a cpu in an fpga, it is indeed a cpu(it's not emulated anymore), sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Marcus Müller So is there anything 32 bit you reccomend? Avr is 8 bit, and arm and x86 is too difficult/big.

Comment: @appmaker1358 I don't know why you keep asking that. I literally recommend one in my answer. Please re-read my answer.

Comment: @appmaker1358 C arrived from 1969-1973, together with Unix. In the time I became involved with the Unix v6 kernel, circa 1978, Unix was going through a "portability" phase and the first published book on C also arrived (I still have my original copy from that year, since I needed to learn C to work on the Unix kernel.) The C development team got a PDP-11 (previously, C was in the process of deriving from B on the PDP-7) in 1970. It's arguable about where the ++ and -- operators came from. But I can, for sure, tell you that generating assembly code for the PDP-11 from C is pretty easy.

Comment: @jonk you never cease to amaze!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've just been lucky enough to work on some fun projects with some interesting people.

Comment: Can only wish you that the fun projects and interesting people stick with you, @jonk :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I worked with Dr. Ken Wickersheim on phosphor thermometry. I worked with Dr. Chris Gronet when G-Squared was just started, prior to acquisition by Applied Materials, and was able to solve (in minutes, immediately on seeing the physics problems) how to measure temperature in their newly developed RTP unit. I remember the Saturday afternoon, very well! (And I think I greatly helped their sale to Applied.) I got to work with the team developing the first successful rewritable CD! I've worked on instruments for the Space Shuttle, brain research, and other bits. I've been very lucky.

Comment: @MarcusMüller There's no good way to make money being a pure basic physics researcher. A good friend, Dr. Saul-Paul Sirag, worked on M-theory (with Dr. Ed Witten, at times) and made about USD3k/yr! You can't live on that. I made money as a programmer. My interests remain with mathematics and physics and I've been lucky enough to secure some nice programming roles near people solving interesting physics problems. I've had the benefit of having my cake and eating it - paid good to work with great folks doing interesting physics and fun mathematics solving meaningful problems. Can't get better.

Comment: @jonk well, I can't (and have no intention to) argue with your sense of being lucky; but also: it's not that these consecutive opportunities just happen and you didn't have to do anything to make the most of them. It certainly takes a lot of work and talent to be able to work in multiple, so interesting places, and achieve something. Kudos :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I do work at self-education, of course. But what matters is what cannot be and isn't really captured in books. It's the ideas and concepts, the ***way*** that great people ***think about*** the world around them. (They aren't always right, but you learn a LOT from just absorbing the tools they use to think with.) It's being around great people who have developed wonderful thinking tools that leaks into you. Something you cannot get from a book and can only get by working with really interesting people. I owe everything to them and the luck of being able to listen to them think.

Comment: This has now turned in to a question that's both a _list question_ and _unclear_. The answers so far are disregarded due to some unwritten criteria of yours (suddenly you don't want a simple and small, you want at least 50 instructions and 32 bits. What else?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Easiest would be to invent my own instruction set

uh, ok, we might come from *very* different experiences here…

> With easiest I mean the least amount of instructions.

That's not necessarily the easiest to implement. Often, having more instructions is a good complexity tradeoff compared to having more complex instructions.

> So my question is, what is the easiest instruction set/architecture that has a (hopefully stable) C++ and/or C compiler?

This sounds like no job for C++, so let's concentrate on C. (If you don't understand the difference having C++ RAII paradigm makes, you might not be in the optimum position to design your own ISA.)

Puh, some microcontroller instruction set that is early, but not *too* early (because too early would imply "designed around the limitations of digital logic of that time, like e.g. 8051).

AVR might be a good choice, though I personally don't like that too much.

I hear Zilog Z80 is easy to implement (there's really several Z80 implementations out there), but it's pretty ancient, and not very comfortable (being from the mid-70s).

If you really just want a small core to control what your system is doing, why not pick one of the many processor core designs that are out there?

For example, RISC-V is a (fairly complex) instruction set architecture, with mature compilers, and many open source implementations. For a minimal FPGA core, picoRV32 would probably the core of choice. And on a computer, you'd just run QEMU.

Comment: RISC-V on QEMU is an excellent option. Also, never knew about the Z80s. What don't you like about AVR?

Comment: It's just that I find the assembler unpleasant to write, and that a lot of the things people use large AVRs with hand-optimized assembler for could be done cheaper and quicker by writing C for a Cortex-M. But that opinion is historically based – in modern days, the ATtiny actually takes a sensible niche.

Comment: C++ compiles to the exact same machine code as C.  Any architecture with the features needed by C also has everything needed by C++.  RAII has absolutely nothing to do with it.

Comment: @BenVoigt point is that if you have a system that has a C++ compiler, chances are very high you'd want to use that to produce OS-targetting code. My reasoning iis that while libc can be pretty hefty, a C++ runtime that actually supports arbitrary C++ (instead of C++ with a lot of custom allocators and potentially std data structures you shouldn't use) does require a memory allocator, and that does influence your desire of your CPU supporting different addressing modes. I've written C++ for Renesas H8300 – it works, but it's really not "stuff for your first CPU".

Comment: @MarcusMüller So... bare metal systems don't play well with most of the C++ library.  How is that different from C?  Dynamic allocation you've already mentioned but there are also file I/O, signals, Bessel functions... a whole bunch of stuff that you won't use unless it is absolutely essential to your project, because implementation on that hardware is so ridiculously inefficient.  On the other hand, templates, RAII, namespaces, member functions are all highly useful for keeping a large software project maintained, no matter the size of the hardware that runs it.

Comment: @BenVoigt so that's the thing about RAII: it encourages (if not practically enforces) usage of dynamic allocation; writing C++ that doesn't inherently do dynamic allocation is neither trivial but comfortable (so I heard from people writing automotive control unit OSes specified to be written in C++ without run-time allocation; you can't use std::string, you can't use std::vector without exchanging the allocator for one only doing allocation before the system switches to the "operational" state, you can't use exceptions at all…).

Comment: The A in RAII stands for "acquisition", not "allocation".  The C library plus the C++ language still makes a better tool than the C library and C language.  Note that OP said nothing about using C++ design patterns, he just asked for a C++ compiler.

Comment: @BenVoigt the strange thing really is I've yet to disagree with you – I'm just willing to bet OP doesn't actually want just a C++ compiler, but a platform to compile arbitrary "common" C++ for :)

Comment: @Marcus Müller I don't want to compile every piece or library for c++. The avr c++ that doesn't have stl would do. I'm not looking for something to implement because I need it. I want to write an emulator for fun, and I want it to support a c/c++ compiler so I can write little programs for it. I don't intend to write an os for it or port linux to it, that's insane. In your begin post you say avr might be a good choice. And I'm willing to implement an avr. ButbI'm more looking for a 32 bit chip with c/cpp support. Do you know anything like that? Also, why is this "no job for c++"?

Comment: So, let's roll this from the bottom: "Do I know a 32 bit CPU I recommend?" Yes, and I did so in my answer. "Why did you say this is 'no job for C++'?" Because you said "little", and if you look at Ben's and my exchange above, we mostly argue about whether "proper" C++ is something you *really* want to do with your first CPU, because you can technically compile any programming language to any turing-complete CPU ISA, but whether it's "little" and "fun" is *really* up for debate.

Comment: @Marcus Müller well, for a first cpu it is a bit much, but if I write an emulator for an existing cpu, it should be able to run c++ right? As long as that cpu can run c++. Or does it take extra effort to get c++ to work? Also, how conplex is risc-v, since you talked about it. Is it as complex as something like arm?

Comment: @appmaker1358 no CPU runs C++. CPUs run machine code, and as long as you have a compiler backend for that language targetting that CPU, you can use that language to write programs for that CPU.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Okay, that's what I thought. Thanks! SO I guess Risc-v is my best bet?

Comment: Not going to repeat myself the third time :)

Comment: The ez80 is a relatively recent z80 descendant, although many times more complicated.

Comment: "if you look at Ben's and my exchange above, we mostly argue about whether "proper" C++ is something you really want to do with your first CPU"  I don't think so.  You weren't claiming that, and I wasn't claiming that embedded code would ever be written in desktop C++ style.  I did say that a C++ compiler is a very valuable tool to have, and for any given platform support library, that library plus a C++ compiler is a better set of tools than that same library plus a C compiler.

Comment: Ok, then let's say we disagree on that :) I do believe that for small platforms, having a C compiler (note that C++ is not just a superset, but does come with things like provisions for exception handling) and a working C lib is probably more helpful than a C++ compiler plus lib. But maybe I'm just a bit overly conservative.

Answer (score 8):

You should take al look at the PIC microcontroller family. The instruction set is limited to 35 different instructions, while the controller is actually still used.
Look at the datasheet at page 228: [PIC16F datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/41291d.pdf)

The controller is using 8 bits and is also available with less periphery, but that does not change anything for the instruction set.

Comment: Pic is interesting, but I prefer something 32 bit. Do you know anything like that?

Comment: Well, I think basically all 32 bit cores are quite more complex in there design, but the MIPS instruction set has (in its initial form) something like 48 instructions. But I think in all relevant implementations this is increased to some extend by more modern versions of MIPS.

Answer (score 7):

You need a [One Instruction Set Computer (OISC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_instruction_set_computer)

> A one instruction set computer (OISC), sometimes called an ultimate
>   reduced instruction set computer (URISC), is an abstract machine that
>   uses only one instruction – obviating the need for a machine language
>   opcode. With a judicious choice for the single instruction
>   and given infinite resources, an OISC is capable of being a universal
>   computer in the same manner as traditional computers that have
>   multiple instructions. OISCs have been recommended as aids in
>   teaching computer architecture and have been used as
>   computational models in structural computing research.

Whether a compiler exists, I do not know. But I suspect some unlucky student somewhere has probably been assigned the task of writing one.

Comment: Okay, this is not really what I'm looking for. With as little instructions as possible, I meant within reason. I don't need as little as possible. I just don't want to implement 2000 different instructions. I hope for something with like 50 instructions. Also, 32 bit and c++.

Comment: Here is a C compiler that compiles to only MOV instructions: [movfuscator](https://github.com/xoreaxeaxeax/movfuscator)

Comment: @Paul: That's not a OISC.  Multiple different opcodes share the same `mov` mnemonic on x86.  (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov).  Also, decoding x86 machine code with ModR/M + SIB addressing modes is not totally trivial.  Compiling to `mov` instructions is pretty horribly inefficient, although so is any OISC.  That probably makes debugging your emulator hard using any real compiler output, because grokking what the machine code is *supposed* to be doing is hard, and so is following it in your head.  I'd go with a simple toy ISA like y86 or a subset of a RISC ISA like MIPS.

Answer (score 7):

A simple instruction set of only 8 instructions used for teaching is known as the MU0 instruction set. It originated at Manchester University and is used for teaching both compiler writing and hardware design. There are several online documents describing it, including class notes at Manchester University.

Bibliography:

- http://digitalbyte.weebly.com/processor-design/the-mu0-processor-instructions ([archived link](https://web.archive.org/web/20191026114229/http://digitalbyte.weebly.com/processor-design/the-mu0-processor-instructions))
- [http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/cs1001/arch/node1.html](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/%7Epjj/cs1001/arch/node1.html) ([archived link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190907052646/http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/%7Epjj/cs1001/arch/node1.html))

Comment: LC-3 is another such toy language for learning.

Answer (score 7):

Donald Knuth's [MMIX architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMIX) has a 64-bit RISC instruction set with 256 opcodes and existing C compilers (GCC, actively maintained) and emulators (mixvm, etc.).

Answer (score 6):

> I hope for something with like 50 instructions. Also, 32 bit and c++

The "Beta" architecture used in MIT's 6.004 core track class is a 32-bit RISC design often referred to as a simplification of the DEC Alpha. It's been implemented in many ways - personally in an FPGA - and at one time there was an old version of GCC for it, though that may at this point be challenging to dig up if no one is continuing to work with it.

One example of the architecture documentation is here, the full link will be retained as which year versions of the course are published online changes from time to time and it can be worth looking at several as different information may be included: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-004-computation-structures-spring-2009/labs/

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be the [LC-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Computer_3) ("Little Computer 3"), which was specifically designed for ECE students to be able to implement a basic CPU in hardware. It's significantly cleaner and easier to emulate than any "real-world" architecture, such as x86's absolute mess of instructions. A [C compiler](http://highered.mheducation.com/sites/0072467509/student_view0/c_to_lc-3_compiler.html) is available for it, though without floating-point support (since the LC-3 doesn't have a FPU).

If you want something that's actively used in the real world, try [MIPS-I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture). MIPS is still widely used on embedded systems, and is best-known for being used in the Nintendo 64 and the Playstation. The standard emulator for it is [SPIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPIM).

(And of course, as other answers have mentioned, Knuth's [MMIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMIX) was made famous by *The Art of Computer Programming*, though unlike the others, to the best of my knowledge, it's never had a true hardware implementation.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a completely serious answer but it might suit your case, if you want to keep the instructions to implement for your emulator low.

In fact the x86 `mov` instruction is turing complete. And there even is a [C compiler](https://github.com/xoreaxeaxeax/movfuscator) for it.

Answer (score -1):

As you found out the simplest is not necessarily the most fun or most useful.  If you are doing this for a learning experience, you might want to look into MMIX which is the RISC architecture used by Knuth for "The Art of Computer Programming".

In other words, an architecture explicitly designed for learning documented accordingly, and with some of the most well-thought out example programs for demonstrating computer science concepts so you can actually do more with it afterwards.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMIX